# Average after group by in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, h2

```
select avg(select count(aid)
           from athlete
           group by codepays)
```

I get a "more than one row error".
How with I go about getting the average of the result from my fist select ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a table expression (subquery).

For example:

```
select avg(cnt)
from (
  select count(aid) as cnt
  from athlete
  group by codepays
) x
```

Comment: Thanks any explanation on why my query isn't working though ?

Comment: The argument of the aggregation functions like `AVG()` are columns or scalar expressions, not queries. Your syntax could theoretically be useful, but it's not part of the SQL Standard (or an extension of it).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using division:

```
select count(aid) / count(distinct codepay)
from athlete;
```

No subqueries are necessary.

(Although the arithmetic needs to be tweaked if `codepay` can actually be `NULL`.)

Comment: Thanks I do know that but I was asked to use group by

Comment: A bit strange.  This is the simplest way to get the results you want.